# How do I make a variable accessible from every method of class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an int named "mode". I want to make every function be able to access it.

Here is my code.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form5 : Form
    {
        public Form5()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int wow = mode - 1;
        }

        private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int mode = 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This really is programming 101. I would suggest looking up how to make objects.

Comment: Write "public" in front of it

Answer (score 2):

Just make it a property of the class.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form5 : Form
{
    public int mode {get; set;}
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int wow = mode - 1;
    }

    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mode = 4;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should remove `int` from the assignment in Form5_Load, otherwise it will hide the property.

Answer (score -2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form5 : Form
{

    public int mode;
    public Form5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int wow = mode - 1;
    }

    private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mode = 4;
    }
}
}
```

However, I'd be surprised if there wasn't a SO page about this. Also I'd recommend looking at MSDN and other programming c#.net resources.

Comment: [There are almost always similar questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36578134/3740093)

Comment: Answer does not provide any explanation for the problem - not helpful.